# How do I clean up old github-sourced gems in bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm working on a gem and have setup my Gemfile (Rails 3.0.9) to download the latest copy from github.  After several updates, I now have a bunch of these different versions installed through bundler, for example:

```
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/test_gem-0.0.1/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-073530fbb227/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-19ca852f2dbc/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-1c54d091fa69/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-2a792620be0e/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-3dc70da90fcb/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-4bb5ca8c3fb5/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-6587eb65715f/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-6e58646ce11d/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-725511907cc1/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-7bc40a7293aa/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-7fceecaf1539/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-9ca2049c33f0/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-b63e6a695990/lib/test_gem.rb
/Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test_gem-be3cfbdd01a2/lib/test_gem.rb
```

bundle exec gem list shows only the latest version:

```
test_gem (0.3.2)
```

bundle exec gem uninstall test_gem -v0.1.0 throws an error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check `gem list -d test_gem`
```

gem list -d test_gem shows nothing

bundle exec gem list -d test_gem does show my gem, but no version info

I suppose I could go in and manually delete these entries, but I figure there's a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show how on mysql2 example:

```
$ gem list mysql2
```

> mysql2 (0.3.7, 0.3.6, 0.3.2, 0.2.7, 0.2.6)

We can first run gem cleanup in dry-run mode to see what would be removed:

```
$ gem cleanup -d
```

> Cleaning up installed gems…
>
> ...
>
> Dry Run Mode: Would uninstall mysql2-0.2.6
>
> Dry Run Mode: Would uninstall mysql2-0.2.7
>
> Dry Run Mode: Would uninstall mysql2-0.3.2
>
> Dry Run Mode: Would uninstall mysql2-0.3.6
>
> ...
>
> Clean Up Complete

Once we are happy with the results, we can run gem cleanup to actually remove the old gems:

```
$ gem cleanup -v
```

**If you do not see test_gem in `gem list -d test_gem*` (notice `*` sign) just try `gem cleanup -d` maybe it will appear in that listing**

in other way - manually - is the best choice!

Comment: This does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
(sudo) rm -rf /Users/jseidel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3/bundler/gems/test*
```

Comment: Not sure that `sudo` is necessary for dealing with one's own home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Bundler provides a way to do this if you must:

```
bundle clean --force
```

It is not recommended since the gems may be used by other projects.

Other options are to use RVM gemsets, in which case you can clear out your gemset with:

```
rvm gemset empty
```